# Admob - number of ad units

Tags: android, admob

I have recently launched my first Android app (good feeling!) It has 10 different pages (fragments), each with its own unique Admob ad unit banner ad.  The user base is still small, around 200 users.  I read that I should have each page with its own ad unit, but it seems that the ads are not making any money with with the small amount of impressions.  Would it not be beneficial to have all the pages use 1 ad unit, then that 1 ad unit would essentiall have more impressions.  Or does it not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any difference, I have used one ad unit in many apps. Inside one app you can reuse ad unit many times. Impressions depends on fill rate and user's activity.

You can try Facebook Audience Network together with admob to increase overall impressions and revenue.

http://hackerseve.com/android-using-together-admob-and-facebook-audience-network/

But remember Facebook ad units can't be reused in multiple apps.